# NoMigrations error in Django

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-south, database-migration

I am building an app called 'competencies'. I made changes to models, migrated the app locally, and everything worked. This is my eighth migration on the app.

I have deployed the app on heroku, so I committed changes and pushed to heroku. I can see that the changes went through, because the new migrations appear in the heroku files. When I log in to heroku and try to migrate the competencies app, I get the following error:

```
NoMigrations: Application '<module 'django.contrib.admin' from '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py'>' has no migrations.
```

I have searched for this error, and I have not found anything meaningful. Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong, or how to address the issue?

Comment: did you apply south migrations to any django models? like `django.contrib.auth` ?

Comment: The only other app I have migrated was admin.

Comment: I guess that is the issue. Are you using virtualenv ? It is not a good idea to apply migrations to any django apps

Comment: I am using virtualenv. What is the best plan to resolve the issue? Can I just delete the migrations dir from django/contrib/admin, or is there a South setting I need to change as well?

Comment: well.. you can just delete the migrations folder. If there are more issues go to `south_migrationhistory` table in the database and remove all the rows pertaining to the `admin` migrations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`django.contrib.admin` should not have migrations. Contrib packages are not south managed.

If you EVER ran `python manage.py schemamigration django.contrib.auth --XXX` on your local it would create the migrations folder in your local copy's install of the venv's django. However, this will never get transferred to heroku.

test something for me. create a new copy of your site on your local machine

- new DB
- new virtualenv
- new folder w/ new clone of repo

try to run `python manage.py migrate` if you get the same error its b/c you broke your virtualenv with south.

Something else you could try IF your database models have not changed a bunch since the last working copy:

- roll your models back to the last working configuration
- delete EVERY app's migrations folder
- truncate `south_migrations` table
- run `python manage.py schemamigration --initial X` for each of your apps.
- push and `migrate --fake`
- redo your model changes
- create migrations for the model changes
- push and migrate regularly

Comment: I tried migrating the admin at one point, and I see the migrations folder in django/contrib/admin. I think I may have tried to migrate the admin in a heroku session at one point as well. I have considered destroying the heroku app and rebuilding that. Is that a reasonable plan, considering it is a test deploy anyway?

Comment: You can keep migrations of your contrib/dependency packages just fine, use `SOUTH_MIGRATION_MODULES = { 'admin', '<project_name>.migrations.admin' }`

Comment: @Hedde http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings.html#south-migration-modules I didnt know about this. In general, I still think its not a great idea to use this feature on the django contrib models as it could break future security fixes etc.

Comment: @japhyr before going through the headache of destroying and re-provisioning your heroku app try to create an isolated version of your app w/ new DB, new virtualenv, new folder w/ new clone of repo and make sure this is works and there isn't some other issue.

Comment: @FrancisYaconiello perhaps, but with django < 1.5 using monkey patching on the User model its a neat helper to get some control over contrib models, one should just know what they are doing :-)

Comment: @Hedde w/ django 1.5 you don't have to monkey patch anymore, you can just specify what model you want to use for managing Users, in which case the model wouldn't be in django.contrib, instead it'd be in your apps somewhere - but either way, what you said about the SOUTH_MIGRATION_MODULES is totally correct. thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I know thats why I defined django < 1.5 :-)

Comment: I think I resolved the issue. I followed your first suggestion; I backed up my dev project, then cloned from the current production version. The new venv removed migrations from the admin app. When I migrated, I got the same error. I'm pretty sure the problem was related to the initial data loading from a fixture. I removed references to admin from the fixture, and removed some records that were causing conflicts. Things seem to work now, so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered this error after dumping a live database to a dev box for testing data migrations.

One of the dependencies was throwing this error (specifically `taggit`). I think that I have a different version of `taggit` on the dev box which does not have migrations, but the database I dumped had two migrations for `taggit` in `south_migrationhistory`.

I deleted the entries in `south_migrationhistory` for the problem app erroneously claiming `NoMigrations` and that solved my problem. Everything's running again.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from many answers posted above, `south.exceptions.NoMigrations` is often exception after 2014 (Django 1.7) because of changed `migrations` directory. The directory is default for Django built in migrations.

For south migration, the directory is `south_migrations`. `South>=1.0` can recognize this and automatically detect migrations. See details [here on Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#libraries-third-party-apps)

In this case, update `South`:

```
pip install -U South
```

Or you can also specify migration directory on settings file (for every app installed).

Answer (score 0):

I found an odd edge case, involving Kombu.

I'm maintaining a legacy Django 1.5 project on Ubuntu 14.04, and I previously had this setting to get Kombu to play nicely:

```
SOUTH_MIGRATION_MODULES = {
    'kombu_transport_django': 'kombu.transport.django.south_migrations',
}
```

However, after I upgraded to Ubuntu 16, there were some minor tweaks in the Python stdlib that again broke Kombu. Upgrading Kombu was the only immediate solution, but that gave me another Kombu error similar to what OP found:

```
NoMigrations: Application '<module 'kombu.transport.django' from '/myproject/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/django/__init__.pyc'>' has no migrations.
```

This error message is nearly worthless, but I eventually realized the problem was my SOUTH_MIGRATION_MODULES setting. It turns out, the old `kombu.transport.django.south_migrations` was removed, and South trying to import this missing migration directory is what was causing the error. The fix was to remove that line.

Answer (score 0):

Try `pip install --upgrade django`

The NoMigrations error often shows up if you downgrade your Django version.

In my case, I had installed a package which automatically uninstalled my current Django version and installed a downgraded it.

Installing the updated version was a quick fix.

Also, you may want to check in your `INSTALLED_APPS` if you have included all of your apps including the `'django.contrib.auth'` and `'django.contrib.admin'`